# Tic Tac Toe - BFS Like Algorithm

Tags: hashmap, tic-tac-toe

I was thinking of my own algorithm to implement Tic Tac toe. It is going to be a computer against system. The algorithm that I thought of implementing would be a hashmap that contains all the winning nodes for each selected node of the user. The system will poll the hash map for the key which the user chose and will select one of the winning move choices randomly. The choices that were selected earlier by the user or the system can be removed or set as boolean true. This would mostly be a blocking based algorithm. Any thoughts or comments on this are welcome.

System Hash map

```
<1,<2,3,4,7,5,9>>
<2,<1,3,5,8>>
<3,<1,2,6,9,5,7>>
<4,<1,7,5,6>>
<5,<2,8,4,6>>
<6,<3,9,5,4>>
<7,<1,4,8,9,5,3>>
<8,<2,5,7,9>>
```

The System would randomly select one of the entries of the hash map based on the user's key selection. I know this is not a very scalable approach but I would like to know some comments on this. Each already selected entry by the system/user can be set as false / removed so thats probably not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach would probably work, but this is not quite a very good solution.

Instead of passing to the system a hard-coded hash containing game states and their respective winning moves, i'd rather implement an algorithm, so the computer could calculate the best moves by itself. Some well known algorithms you might consider:

[Minimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax)

[Negamax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negascout)

[Alpha-beta pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning)

Also, by using an algorithm, you'll add scalability to your program.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen this algorithms but haven't gone ahead to implement them. My game play logic is hardcoded but when I went ahead in implementing this, I couldn't really tame the behavior of the system. It was Harder in some runs and easier in others as the entrants were completely random. I am looking to ascertain levels of difficulty in the game and I think Minimax for easy, alpha beta for medium would be the best way to go. Any other thoughts are completely welcome as well. Thanks for your comment